# How to count how many times values in range appear in a range, excluding an other range

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to count how many times values in an range are appearing in other specified range of values, and I want to exclude a specific range and blank values.

**Here's an example of what I'm trying to do :**

Here's the formula I'm using to get Number of values of range `C2:C11` excluding `A2:A3` values and **blank** cells :

```
=COUNTIFS({C2:C11};"<>"&{A2:A3};{C2:C11};"<>")
```

[image]

But unfortunately it isn't doing what I aim to do.
Here it gives me 7 but I would expect 3.

It's like, if I write `"<>"&{A2:A3}` it only excludes the first value of the specified range `{A2:A3}`, meaning `A2`.

Any clue on how to make it exclude all values of range ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=COUNTA(filter(B2:B; isna(match(B2:B; A2:A;0))))
```

As in this picture:

[image]

Link to working copy:

[Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16B9uEyuz6FXEfzD8HVvPG_2S2LfYUCVXM8_HO0moaYY/edit#gid=0)

Is this what you where up to?

Comment: Wow, nice ! That does the job !
Thank you very much sir !

Comment: Glad I could help